# Replace a specific value from ALL attributes in an element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this HTML code with multiple attributes that have the same link to an image, I need to replace two parts from the link, from '*imageONE*' to '*imageTWO*' and '*v123*' to '*v456*'. How can I do this in one go without having to select each attribute one by one?

**Change From This:**

```
<img src="//website.com/imageONE_100x.jpg?v=123" data-src="//website.com/imageONE_200x.jpg?v=123" data-sizes="auto" data-srcset="//website.com/imageONE_300x.jpg?v=123" height="100" width="100" srcset="//website.com/imageONE_400x.jpg?v=123">
```

**To this:**

```
<img src="//website.com/imageTWO_100x.jpg?v=456" data-src="//website.com/imageTWO_200x.jpg?v=456" data-sizes="auto" data-srcset="//website.com/imageTWO_300x.jpg?v=456" height="100" width="100" srcset="//website.com/imageTWO_400x.jpg?v=456">
```

I tried 'document.body.innerHTML.replace', even tho this works, it gets rid of all binding and messes up website functionality.

Thanks very much!

Comment: Is it always `<img>` elements? Is there anything common to those elements that would help identifying them?

Comment: WIth jquery, you can easily loop through all of the `<img>` tags.  That's the way to do it.

Comment: @Phil Its just one <img> element, I can add an ID to it if it makes it easier?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get all the attribute names via [getAttributeNames()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttributeNames), iterate them and perform the replacements

```js
document.querySelectorAll("img").forEach((img) => {
  for (let attr of img.getAttributeNames()) {
    img.setAttribute(
      attr,
      img
        .getAttribute(attr)
        .replaceAll("imageONE", "imageTWO")
        .replaceAll("v=123", "v=456"),
    );
  }
});

console.log(document.querySelector("div").innerHTML);
```

```html
<div>
<img src="//website.com/imageONE_100x.jpg?v=123" data-src="//website.com/imageONE_200x.jpg?v=123" data-sizes="auto" data-srcset="//website.com/imageONE_300x.jpg?v=123" height="100" width="100" srcset="//website.com/imageONE_400x.jpg?v=123">
</div>
```

Comment: This works! Thank you very much Phil!!! :D